# How to add a property in model without adding it to form View in ASP .NET MVC code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to add a property in model where it will not be visible in form View. The property will stay in model and database only. I want to know the entity framework code first approach of this process including migration.

Comment: Your model can have as many properties you want to have.and you can decide which properties you want to display in the view. There is no rule that you have to display all the properties of model in the view

Comment: yes, But when I create a controller and select the model class it automatically creates the view.

Comment: You can always edit view manually to remove unnecessary properties from display.

Comment: You can have two models, one for the form view and the other for the database. The database one can have as many different properties as you want and translate the form view one to that of the database.